# React SWR fetch undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, swr

Hi I am trying to fetch data from API with apiKey.
But get undefined

```
const fetchTest = (url, key) => {
 fetch(url, {
 method: 'GET',
 headers: {
   Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'X-AUTH-TOKEN': key
 }
 }).then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseData)=> responseData);
};


const { data, error } = useSWR(['api/link','apiKey'], (url, key) => fetchTest(url, key));
```

If I try to `console.log(data)` always get undefined.
But strange thing if I will use `console.log()` inside of `fetchTest()` right after
`.then((responseData)=> responseData)` and will do something like `.then((response) => response.json()).then((responseData)= console.log(responseData))`
I get exactly what I need. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the fetch.

you should put the return statement before the fetch or remove the curly bracers like this => fetch